# CSS Gradients in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, css

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xEULj/

```
#rt-header {
width: 600px;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, red 40%, green 40%, green);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, red 40%, green 40%, green);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, red 40%, green 40%, green);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, red, red 40%, green 40%, green);
background: linear-gradient(left, red, red 40%, green 40%, green);
}
```

Has there been a way to make this happen in IE yet? Some work-around that I have yet to find? I've actually just found out that this doesn't work in IE10, I thought it would, coming from here: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html, but I guess not.

Any ideas, or do I just need to use an image?

Comment: You could try a gradient generator like: [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Works just fine in Chrome... I took the code straight from the Microsoft site and ran a prefixer on it in Sublime Text... possible something occurred, but it's not showing anything wrong in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Your code seems to be outdated. The unprefixed version should have 'to right' instead of 'left', because the syntax has changed again before browsers unprefixed it. Also, there is no need in `-ms-linear-gradient` since IE9 doesn't understand CSS gradients at all, and IE10 understands the unprefixed syntax.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want something that works in at least IE8, or just IE10 will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements to fill the given part of the element with the solid color:

```
#rt-header {
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

#rt-header:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[EDITED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xEULj/2/)

Should work in IE8 (tested with netrenderer.com).

Comment: This worked better than the solution that Ali provided. Although both answers are probably correct, this actually produced the desired result in IE8, whereas Ali's produced an actual gradient.

Answer (score 3):

There is IE10 support below with gradient going from green to red.

[**CHECK THIS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xEULj/3)

```
#rt-header
        {
    background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 1%, #ff2828 49%, #3fff30 49%, #3fff00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(1%,#ff3232), color-stop(49%,#ff2828), color-stop(49%,#3fff30), color-stop(100%,#3fff00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 1%,#ff2828 49%,#3fff30 49%,#3fff00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 1%,#ff2828 49%,#3fff30 49%,#3fff00 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 1%,#ff2828 49%,#3fff30 49%,#3fff00 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 1%,#ff2828 49%,#3fff30 49%,#3fff00 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#3fff00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
        }
```

Comment: This works! Except I need a hard edge line down the center instead of the gradient, just as my jsfiddle example hopefully showed (the hard edge between the green and red).

Comment: Yes, a great tool! Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, old IE filters can't create hard edges between colors and color stops at all, they can produce only simplest 2-color gradients. But they support alpha transparency. Also, colorzilla's generator produces the redundant `-ms-linear-gradient` string, too.

Comment: It's OK in IE10 and modern browsers, but IE9 and below still render the smooth gradient.

Comment: That code works, except in IE8, it gives a gradient, with no hard edge... The answer code give me a hard edge in all versions of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might need to use the to keyword.

try background: linear-gradient(to right, red, red 40%, green 40%, green);